# how to deal with DOM walks and while loop related no-loop-func issues in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

reading a few questions on here, and reading through the docs: I'm still a bit confused about how to fix this warning of no-loop-func:

```js
function scrollHorizontally(e,listOfBannedClasses, parentClass){
    //truncated example
    let target = e.target;
    while(target.parentNode!== null && target.className!==parentClass &&target.parentNode!== undefined){
        if(listOfBannedClasses.some(x=>target.parentNode.classList.contains(x)))
            {
            return;
        }      
        target = target.parentNode;
    
    }
}
```

I understand that the problem stems from target being defined outside the while loop.
but I'm not using a function of any kind to reassign it: it just walks up a node tree.
what I am trying to do is to get the highest element of the DOM tree possible that is below a 'banned class' from the element clicked on.

is there a cleaner way of doing that then this code?

Comment: You assingning target to its parentNode. Why do you want to do?

Comment: as I explained in the question: target is = to the node which is highest in the DOM tree that is below a 'banned class' - but I have to walk the tree to find that node.

Comment: It wants you to declare `const predicate = x=>target.parentNode.classList.contains(x);` outside of the loop. But seriously, there's nothing wrong with your code, just ignore that weird rule.

Comment: thank you for verifying there isn't anything wrong: but is there a walk to 'walk up the dom' like i'm doing without triggering this warning (or any warning) ?

Comment: again: thank you for your insight :) I've gotten rid of the warning.